# python csv module error

Tags: python, csv

When I use Pythons [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module, it shows me

```
"delimiter" must be an 1-character string"
```

My code is  like this

```
 sep = ","
 srcdata = cStringIO.StringIO(wdata[1])
 data = csv.reader(srcdata, delimiter=sep)
```

`wdata[1]` is a string source.

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Can you post the actual error message that you receive?

Comment: You should accept Mahmoud's answer -- click on the checkmark near it.

Answer (score 31):

You most likely have `from __future__ import unicode_literals` at the top of your module or you are using python 3.x+ You need to do something like this:

```
sep=b","  # notice the b before the "
srcdata=cStringIO.StringIO(wdata[1])
data = csv.reader(srcdata,delimiter=sep)
```

This tells Python that you want to represent `","` as a byte string instead of a unicode literal.

Comment: I now get TypeError: delimiter must be set under Python 3.3 and "delimiter" must be a 1-character string under Python 3.2.